# PHP: access to directory from file

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, chmod

The file *test.php*:

```
./foo/test.php [-rwxr-xr-x user1]
```

doesn't have an access to the *bar* directory (in the same directory):

```
./foo/bar/ [drwxr-xr-x user1]
```

until permissions are changed to:

```
./foo/bar/ [drwxrwxrwx user1]
```

How to get access to the *bar* directory from the *test.php* file without changing permissions?

Comment: It's not about the permissions of the php file itself, it is about the permission of the user that is running the php file; the web-server normally.

Comment: change owner to www-data. may be this is the user

Answer (score 0):

file permissions are handled by os not by files. you need to give access permission to the user that running the application . most in linux based web apps . www-data will be the user. ether give permission or change owner to www-data.